# Is there a loaded tour guide to Edubuntu?

Tags: edubuntu

I just installed Edubuntu and the computer will go to a pair of young little girls, the system is already running bu I would like to show them a guided tour on how to use and discover Edubuntu, I noticed there was a presentation slideshow while installing it but I just thought I could get access to it later on, now I just don't find anything like it, if possible I need it in Spanish.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description for package edubuntu-live-welcome says:

> Displays an introduction to Edubuntu on login. It is meant to give users who are completely new to Edubuntu (and Ubuntu for that matter) a basic idea of how to navigate the system and what to expect.

Does that sound like what you want?

```
sudo apt-get install edubuntu-live-welcome
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you in on the fact I became a developer a year ago and found this question I asked 5 years ago in the Ubuntu chat now showing up on my SOF account.Thank you for your help back then.

Answer (score 0):

The installer video does not really show alot and is removed after installation. Youtube can help you here since there is a website for [edubuntu related video's](http://www.edubuntu.org/2011/01/24/youtube-highlights) and a special [youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/edubuntuproject?feature=mhum) that shows a lot.

I also found this one in spanish: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx9-Wf8JSu8

The best way of learning is doing it yourself (but a little help from a little more experienced user might help).